# Can't seem to get my function working JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can someone find a reason why my function does not work.

```
function iMenu() {

    var Isotope = prompt('Enter the name of the Isotope');
    var HalfLife = prompt('Enter the Half-Life');
    var Quantity = prompt('Enter the Quantity');
    var Timescale = prompt('Enter the Timescale');
    var Count = 0;
    var Period = 0;

    While(Quantity < 1); {
        Quantity = (Quantity / 2);
        Count = (Count + 1);
    }

    Period = (HalfLife * Count);
    alert('The decay period for + Quantity + of + Isotope + is + period + + Timescale +');

}
```

I'm still a beginner with JavaScript

Comment: remove the ; at the end of the while statement

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive. `while !== While`

Comment: You have a couple things that are causing your script to not work or return wrong values, with an extra semicolon as well as what appears to be incorrect concatenation. Take a look at your console as you work, it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Nothing happens after I enter a string for Timescale. I'm trying to get the alert box say "The decay period for (Quantity) of (Isotope) is (period) (Timescale)"

Comment: JSLint or [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) are your friends.

Comment: Ok, fixed the case sensitive bit. How do you use concatenation in JavaScript?

Comment: "Does not work" is a very poor description of the problem. Code is much easier to read when you have insight into what it's supposed to do and what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop should not have a semicolon between the condition and the opening bracket. Also, don't capitalize while.

Replace:

```
While (Quantity < 1);
{
Quantity = (Quantity / 2);
Count = (Count + 1);
}
```

With:

```
while (Quantity < 1){
Quantity = (Quantity / 2);
Count = (Count + 1);
}
```

As a helpful tip, you can use shorthand so your while loop looks like this:

```
while (Quantity < 1){
Quantity /= 2;
Count += 1;
}
```

Your alert should look like this:

```
alert('The decay period for ' + Quantity + ' of ' + Isotope + ' is ' + Period + ', ' + Timescale);
```

Answer (score 0):

No semicolon in the while loop:

```
while(Quantity < 1) {
    Quantity = (Quantity / 2);
    Count = (Count + 1);
}
```

And concatenate your strings correctly, something like this:

```
alert('The decay period for ' + Quantity + ' of ' + Isotope + ' is ' + Period + ', ' + Timescale);
```

Comment: Quantity  is a string